# Extract string between exact word and pattern using stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have been wondering how to extract string in R using stringr or another package between the exact word "to the" (which is always lowercase) and the very second comma in a sentence.

For instance:

String: "This not what I want to the THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?, this is not what I want"

Desired output: "THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?"

I have this vector:

```
x<-c("This not what I want to the THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?, this is not what I want",
     "HYU_IO TO TO to the I WANT, THIS, this i dont, want", "uiui uiu to the xxxx,,this is not, what I want")
```

and I am trying to use this code

```
str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=to the ).*(?=\\,)")
```

but I cant seem to get it to work to properly give me this:

```
"THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?" 
"I WANT, THIS"           
"xxxx,"
```

Thank you guys so much for your time and help

Comment: Is it safe to assume that "to the" comes before **both** commas as in your examples? If the input was `"A, to the B, C, D"` should the result be `"B, C"` or just `"B"`?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment! it is safe to assume that no comma will appear before "to the" if they do then they sould be ignored, so for your example the proper output will be "B, C"

Comment: Do you *only* want "THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?" or do you also want "I WANT, THIS"?  The first half of your question assumes you only want the first, can you clarify exactly what you would want to return from `x`?

Comment: @jpsmith the output in the question is the exact output to return from `x`. I added code formatting so it's a bit easier to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close!

```
str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=to the )[^,]*,[^,]*")
# [1] "THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?"
# [2] "I WANT, THIS"                       
# [3] "xxxx,"
```

The look-behind stays the same, `[^,]*` matches anything but a comma, then `,` matches exactly one comma, then `[^,]*` again for anything but a comma.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a rock star can you please reference a good article on regex or stringr Im just a student! thank you so much!

Comment: I learned regex mostly from projects and questions here on SO. I use regex101.com a lot for debugging and I keep a cheatsheet I found online handy. Look over the cheatsheet and make sure you understand the core concept of everything, but finding the way to use the concepts to solve problems like this is mostly learned through practice.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, by far not comparable with Gregor Thomas approach, but somehow an alternative:

1. vector to tibble
2. separate twice by first `to the` then by `,`
3. paste together
4. pull for vector output.

```
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(x) %>% 
  separate(value, c("a", "b"), sep = 'to the ') %>% 
  separate(b, c("a", "c"), sep =",") %>% 
  mutate(x = paste0(a, ",", c), .keep="unused") %>% 
  pull(x)
```

```
[1] "THIS IS WHAT I WANT, DO YOU SEE IT?"
[2] "I WANT, THIS"                       
[3] "xxxx,"
```